# twitcurl OAuth - Error 89: Invalid/Expired Token

Tags: c++, linux, twitter, twitter-oauth

I use twitcurl to OAuth twitter and send direct messages. I set all keys :

```
 twitCurl twitterObj;
    twitterObj.getOAuth().setConsumerKey(t_consumer_key);
    twitterObj.getOAuth().setConsumerSecret(t_consumer_secret);
    twitterObj.getOAuth().setOAuthTokenKey(t_access_token);
    twitterObj.getOAuth().setOAuthTokenSecret(t_access_token_secret);
    twitterObj.accountVerifyCredGet();

The twitterObj.getLastWebResponse(replyMsg); return error 89:
    <error code="89">Invalid or expired token</error>
```

Can I to Oauth with access token(s) instead of username/password?

PS: Access level is "Read, write, and direct messages"

Answer (score 0):

I use next calling sequence:

//#define IF_FALSE_RETURN( a ) if(!a) { log("TwitterClient authorizetion failed!"); return;}

```
    twitterCurl->setTwitterUsername(usr);
    twitterCurl->setTwitterPassword(pwd);

    twitterCurl->getOAuth().setConsumerKey(twitterConsumerKey);
    twitterCurl->getOAuth().setConsumerSecret(twitterConsumerSecret);

    std::string authorizedUrl;

    IF_FALSE_RETURN( twitterCurl->oAuthRequestToken(authorizedUrl)  );
    IF_FALSE_RETURN( twitterCurl->oAuthHandlePIN(authorizedUrl)     );
    IF_FALSE_RETURN( twitterCurl->oAuthAccessToken()                );

    twitterCurl->getOAuth().getOAuthTokenKey(accessTokenTwitter);
    twitterCurl->getOAuth().getOAuthTokenSecret(accessSecretTwitter);
```

IF_FALSE_RETURN - very important! 
If one method returned false next calls can return true and assign token and secret, but user authorization is failed.